# There's a cycle in the delegation calls chain error in Kotliln constructor

Tags: kotlin

> I create two secondary constructor in entity class  in first
> constructor I want to pass String values, and in second secondary
> constructor I want to pass the entity class data but I get error in
> first secondary constructor where I pass the String data
> I get this type of error in UserEntity constructor

```
There's a cycle in the delegation calls chain
```

> User.kt

```
package com.nilmani.mychat.model

import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document
import java.time.LocalDate


@Document
open  class User(
    @Id
    var id: String ="",
    var userName:String="",
    private var password:String="",
    var email:String="",
    var createdAt:LocalDate=LocalDate.now(),
    var updatedAt:LocalDate= LocalDate.now(),
    var active:Boolean=false,
    @NotNull
    var userProfile:Profile,
    @NotNull
    var role:MutableSet<Role> = HashSet()
) {
    constructor(
                userName: String,
                password: String,
                email: String,
                ) : this(userName,password,email){
                     this.userName= userName
                     this.password=password
                     this.email = email
    }
    constructor(user:User):
            this(user.id,user.userName,
                user.password,user.email,
                user.createdAt,user.updatedAt,
            user.active,user.userProfile,
            user.role){
                this.id=user.id,
                this.userName=user.userName
                this.password = user.password
                this.email = user.email
                this.createdAt = user.createdAt
                this.updatedAt = user.updatedAt
                this.active  = user.active
                this.userProfile = user.userProfile
                this.role = user.role
            }
}
```

> I get error at this keyword on first constructor decleration

Answer (score 1):

You are delegating to the same `constructor`, which forms a loop and causes the error.

From [kotlin spec](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/declarations.html#constructor-declaration)

> If a class has a primary constructor, any secondary constructor must
> delegate to either the primary constructor or to another secondary
> constructor via this(...).
>
> In all cases, it is forbidden if two or more secondary constructors
> form a delegation loop.

To solve this try to call the primary `constructor` or the one that expects `User` object as argument

```
constructor(userName: String, 
            password: String, 
            email: String): this(userName = userName, 
                                 password = password, 
                                 email = email, 
                                 userProfile = someDefaultValue) {
        
}
```